# Finding K-nearest neighbors

Tags: matlab, knn

I need to implement KNN algorithm to classify data.
I have a test matrix (200*25) and a train matrix (800*25).
I need to find KNN and its precision in matlab
for k=1,3,5.

This is my code so far, but I am not sure:

```
clc
clear all
close all

train=load('Train.txt');
[rtrain,ctrain]=size(train);
xtrain=zeros(rtrain,ctrain-1);
xtrain=train(:,1:ctrain-1);


test=load('Test.txt');
[rtest,ctest]=size(test);
xtest=zeros(rtest,ctest-1);
xtest=test(:,1:ctest-1);


dist=zeros(rtrain,1);
N = size(rtrain,1);
dists = zeros(N,1);
for idx = 1 : N
    for j=1:rtrain
    dists(idx) = sqrt(sum((xtest(idx,:) - xtrain(j,:)).^2))
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
xtrain=zeros(rtrain,ctrain-1);
xtrain=train(:,1:ctrain-1);
```

is redundant. You only need the second statement.

And here again:

```
dist=zeros(rtrain,1);
N = size(rtrain,1);
dists = zeros(N,1);
```

except that now you used `dist` and `dists`. You just wanted the second assignment -- the first one actually overrides Matlab's `dist` function.

So, back to k-NN. This

```
for idx = 1 : N
    for j=1:rtrain
        dists(idx) = sqrt(sum((xtest(idx,:) - xtrain(j,:)).^2))
    end
end
```

gives you the distance between test instance `idx` versus all training instances `j=1,2,...rtrain`. Great, that's almost the 1-NN. Now all you have to do is find the smallest distance and check the class labels.

To find the index of the nearest neighbor, you can do this:

```
[~, neighbour] = min(dists);
```

`min` returns two values: the minimum and the index of the minimum. With this code you are ignoring the distance and taking only the index of the nearest neighbor.

To extend this code for k-NN, use `sort` instead of `min`. It behaves similarly.

Comment: I am grateful If k> 1 explain this to me and Write Code